# Are Location aware notification on iOS possible in Phonegap, Corona or Monotouch?

Tags: geolocation, xamarin.ios, cordova, uilocalnotification, coronasdk

Like everyone else I'm venturing into mobile app-development and I'm looking at different frameworks / languages. The ones that look most appealing to me are Phonegap, Corona SDK and Monotouch. Objective C seems to be a little too low level. I haven't done memory management for a long time and I'm not yearning to relive that experience. But if that's where I need to go to meet the client's need, I'll go there.

The client in this case needs location aware notifications in an iOS app.

A user story goes like this: The user is out walking the town. She's got her iPhone in her pocket and is listening to music via iTunes. As she walks into her local mall my app (running in the background) detects that she is in the proximity of a branch of her bank. My app also knows that the user has some errand to do at the bank. So my app interrupts the currently playing iTunes track, plays a notification sound and puts a notification text on the screen, telling the user that there's a bank office nearby and that she might want to do that bank errand now.

Could this be done with either Phonegap, Corona SDK or Monotouch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MonoTouch supports all types of iOS location services (standard, significant location change and region monitoring) so yes, you can do it with MonoTouch.

Comment: what about the phonegap? does it support?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Apple has started bringing in geo-location notifications with the Reminders app I'm fairly certain that it won't be exposed in the higher level frameworks as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Some good info here in the [Apple developer docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24)

> There are several ways to track the user’s location in the background,
>   most of which do not actually require your app to run continuously in
>   the background:
>
> - The significant-change location service (Recommended)
> - Foreground-only location services
> - Background location services
>     ...

All are possible with MonoTouch. Pretty sure they are with PhoneGap also. Don't know about Corona.